# Paste text as formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a string that is a formula. Like in here (this is a simpler example)
If:

```
A1 is "Sum"
A2 is "D3"
```

Then B1 is `=Concatenate("=",A1,"(",A2,")")`

I want a VBA macro that takes the **result** of the formula in B1 and paste is **as a formula** in C1.

I need C1 to be the formula `=SUM(D3)`

I think it involves the PasteSpecial and evaluate, but I can't figure out how.

I don't want to use the INDIRECT function because I want to be able to fill more cells using than formula and the relative references inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with Activesheet
  .Range("C1").Formula = .Range("B1").Value
End With
```

Comment: the 'with' is a dangerous road imho. (but it doesn't change your answer's value, of course)

Comment: Just a side note for you guys. If you have an addin and try to create the formula on the add-in it only works some of the time. Don't ask me why, I have no idea. Eventually I had to write it directly to the sheet I was working with. Also, another oddity, you have to write each formula individually to each cell, you can't have a 2-d array and write it to multiple cells at once, don't know why but annoying to say the least.

Comment: @Tim : It seems like every times I'm using a 'with', I end up wanting to take part of the block out when I rearrange the code so I must reedit and all. Maybe I shouldn't have said "Dangerous". I just prefer using objets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you explicitly want a command macro, but this thing seems like a great use of a VBA UDF. If you create the UDF:

```
Function EvalFormula(f As String) As Variant
    EvalFormula = Application.Evaluate(f)
End Function
```

Then in C1 you can call:

```
=EvalFormula(B1)
```

Writing this as a UDF is going to eliminate those unpleasant situations where you forgot to run your macro and now your sheet is all out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Formula = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Value` to use the text value as a formula

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
```

You can work the rest from that I'd assume :-)

Comment: This sets the value, not the formula.

Comment: Have you tried? Before saying it doesn't work, do your homeworks.